# ScrollView block some action

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a `ScrollView` which englobes some `TextView`.
When I press on a textView there's a "`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP/DOWN`" method which make a textSize change, then after 2s the size text change again.

```
Handler handler5 = new Handler();
handler5.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Presence.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 60);
    }

}, 2000);
```

With the `ScrollView`, the text doesn't change again after 2 seconds, any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean, that the text doesn't change when the TextView is in the ScrollView?

Comment: If i touch my textView the text size change, but if i scrool, the textSize wont change again after my 2s delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CountDownTimer Class like this:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Presence.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 30);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Presence.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 60);
    }
}
```

Then call that class like this:

```
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
```

Comment: It Works ! Thanks you :)